# Reduce memory usage of broadcast and sum

Tags: python, numpy

How to do the following with less memory?

The `a * b` is using 9 times more memory than necessary.

Is it possible to replace `np.sum(a * b, axis=3)` with a `np.tensordot`?

Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.choice(100, size=(23, 10, 3))
a = x[:, :, np.newaxis, :]
b = x[:, np.newaxis, :, :]
y = np.sum(a * b, axis=3)
```

Comment: that list method at the duplicate is slow. I thik numpy's einsum is not parallelized by mkl, unlike dot and tensordot.

Comment: Use `einsum` one. Play around with `opimize` flag as True that uses BLAS.

Comment: where is the `optimize` flag?

Comment: In the documentation.

Comment: ok. you mean the optimize flag of einsum instead of the definition of the backend.

Comment: `np.einsum(...., optimize=True)` and without the flag set as True, i.e. default one - False and see which one works best.

Comment: My times show `einsum` optimize True is slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [749]: x = np.random.choice(100, size=(23, 10, 3)) 
     ...: a = x[:, :, np.newaxis, :] 
     ...: b = x[:, np.newaxis, :, :] 
     ...: y = np.sum(a * b, axis=3)                                             
In [750]: a.shape                                                               
Out[750]: (23, 10, 1, 3)           # a view, no extra memory
In [751]: b.shape                                                               
Out[751]: (23, 1, 10, 3)
In [752]: y.shape                                                               
Out[752]: (23, 10, 10)
In [753]: (a*b).shape                                                           
Out[753]: (23, 10, 10, 3)          # 3x larger than y
```

I'm not sure how you count the 9 times too much.

This can also be expressed with `einsum`:

```
In [758]: np.einsum('ijl,ikl->ijk', x, x).shape                                 
Out[758]: (23, 10, 10)
In [759]: np.allclose(np.einsum('ijl,ikl->ijk', x, x),y)                        
Out[759]: True
```

I'm not sure how its memory use compares.  In the original form it iterated over a 'ijkl' space.

It's a little faster:

```
In [760]: timeit np.einsum('ijl,ikl->ijk', x, x).shape                          
74.1 µs ± 256 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [761]: timeit y = np.sum(a * b, axis=3)                                      
90.9 µs ± 86.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

It took a little more work, but I found a faster way, using `matmul`:

```
In [771]: (a@b.transpose(0,1,3,2)).shape                                        
Out[771]: (23, 10, 1, 10)
In [772]: np.allclose((a@b.transpose(0,1,3,2)).squeeze(),y)                     
Out[772]: True
In [773]: timeit (a@b.transpose(0,1,3,2)).shape                                 
20 µs ± 28 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This moves more of the work to fast compiled libraries.  I can't speak for the memory use.

The simpler solution found in the duplicate like is a bit faster:

```
In [777]: timeit (x@x.transpose(0,2,1)).shape                                   
18.4 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: may bad it is 3 times more.